# How to download Jquery if link only shows source code and connect it to my html

Tags: jquery, css, html

**I am working with jQuery for the first time and I cant get it to download.**
I am new at posting. I apologize if I did not get it done properly; any constructive criticism is welcome.
     I am very new to coding. I've 3 quarters in college now and have been in  intro to C#, Ruby, html, SQL, JS, and PS.  I know data types, functions, variables , and loops...yet I know very little syntax by heart and I am really struggling. 
     **I need help expressed at the novice level hopefully in clear and  easy steps to get my jQuery going from download to working.**
     I feel a bit stupid, but I have been at this for too long and need assistance. I am sure it is fairly simple for someone familiar with it. Will someone please HELP!!!! I spent too much time trying with no result ....

In order to do this I understand that I need paste a Jquery library file "Download the uncompressed, development jQuery 1.11.3"
and...."Download the uncompressed, development jQuery Migrate 1.2.1"
from the jQuery official site.

I have tried to download it but all I get is the source file. I watched utube vids to learn, but did not find much and what I did find was geared towards a specific tutorial objective and I could not assimilate it.

I understand that in order to get my jQuery library in my html I need this:

Not sure if it goes in the head or body of html....I think I have it in the correct spot?
I was told I have to add http: in front my CDN.

And I am trying to accomplish this:

How my page is supposed to work.
Page loads with all headings closed. When the user clicks on a heading with a plus sign, the text below is displayed and the plus sign changes to a minus sign. If the user clicks on a heading with a minus sign, the text hides and the sign changes to a plus.

I have an html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FAQs</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="faqs.js"></script>     

</head>

<body>
    <section id="faqs">
        <h1>jQuery FAQs</h1>
        <h2><a href="#" id="first_link">What is jQuery?</a></h2>
        <div>
            <p>jQuery is a library of the JavaScript functions that you're most likely 
               to need as you develop web sites.
            </p>
        </div>
        <h2><a href="#">Why is jQuery becoming so popular?</a></h2>
        <div>
            <p>Three reasons:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>It's free.</li>
                <li>It lets you get more done in less time.</li>
                <li>All of its functions are cross-browser compatible.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h2><a href="#">Which is harder to learn: jQuery or JavaScript?</a></h2>
        <div>
            <p>For most functions, jQuery is significantly easier to learn 
                and use than JavaScript. But remember that jQuery is JavaScript.
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have a .css page:

```
/* type selectors */
article, aside, figure, figcaption, footer, header, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
section {
    padding: 15px 25px;
}
h1 { 
    font-size: 150%;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
    padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(images/plus.png) no-repeat left center;
}
h2.minus {
    background: url(images/minus.png) no-repeat left center;
}
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h2:hover {background-color: #ccccff;}
a:focus, a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
div {
    display: none;
}
div.open {
    display: block;
}
ul {
    padding-left: 45px;
}
li {
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}
p {
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

and two .png images that are a and a minus plus signs.
```

Comment: `file save as` ... and voila, it's downloaded. Then simply point a script tag at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("h2 a").click(function() {
     var s = $(this).attr('id');
     $('.' + s).show();
   });
 });
```

```css
/* type selectors */

article,
aside,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
section {
  padding: 15px 25px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 120%;
  padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(images/plus.png) no-repeat left center;
}
h2.minus {
  background: url(images/minus.png) no-repeat left center;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h2:hover {
  background-color: #ccccff;
}
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
div {
  display: none;
}
div.open {
  display: block;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 45px;
}
li {
  padding-bottom: .25em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="faqs">
  <h1>jQuery FAQs</h1>
  <h2><a href="#" id="first_link">What is jQuery?</a></h2>
  <div class=first_link>
    <p>jQuery is a library of the JavaScript functions that you're most likely to need as you develop web sites.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h2><a href="#" id="second_link">Why is jQuery becoming so popular?</a></h2>
  <div class=second_link>
    <p>Three reasons:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>It's free.</li>
      <li>It lets you get more done in less time.</li>
      <li>All of its functions are cross-browser compatible.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h2><a href="#" class=third_link>Which is harder to learn: jQuery or JavaScript?</a></h2>
  <div class=third_link>
    <p>For most functions, jQuery is significantly easier to learn and use than JavaScript. But remember that jQuery is JavaScript.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

`The line

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

loads jQuery library on your webpage.

what you need to do it based on what your requirements.

you will need JavaScript code to accomplish the task

Comment: First of all....I have to thank you for your help. It sounds like jQuery 1.11 is the best chioce for my needs. So the libray contains code snippets compiled in JavScript language? I can copy and paste a function or method that does a specific thing? what kind of things

Comment: sorry...I meant to edit that and I was not ready to send it... one moment please. I am viewing the jquery source code now. ...... the rest makes sense, very well explained.

Answer (score 1):

You are including jquery correctly, as in your `<head>` section you have the following:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Here you including the version 1.9.1 of jquery, however at the time of this answer there two last versions of it, the 1.11.3 and 2.1.4, it is the same just differ in supporting internet explorer version 8 and below browser, if you need to supporse these browsers then use the 1.x version,  if not use the 2.x version as mentioned in here http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-2-x

> jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8. All the notes in the jQuery 1.9 Upgrade Guide apply here as well. Since IE 8 is still relatively common, we recommend using the 1.x version unless you are certain no IE 6/7/8 users are visiting the site.

So download the 1.11 version and you're safe.

As where to include jquery in your webpage, it could be in the `head` part or at the bottom of the page before `</body>` but remember all coding you are going to do with jquery needs to be done or included after you include jquery in your page.

If you intend to load it in the head make sure to write your jquery functions inside `$(document).ready(function{ /*your code here */});` so that it wait until the HTML DOM is ready, but if you are going to include it before closing the `body` at the bottom of the page then it is not necessary to wrap it in the `document.ready()` function.

Remember that always include the production minified `.min.js` file because it is compressed and with less size - *97KB comparing to 277KB in case of the uncompressed one* - and you don't really need the development version in most cases

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all you get is the source code. It looks like you've not worked with JavaScript before. JavaScript is compiled at runtime. So, you don't have to compile it. The source code is the JavaScript program. That's how it's distributed. Just get that source code from the jQuery website, and paste it in a `jquery.js` file somewhere in your project. Then, you can link it with:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

This code works only if your html page and jquery are in the same directory. If you decide to put `jquery.js` inside a `js` folder, you would have use this code instead:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

That code should go somewhere in the `<head>` section of your website, or before closing the `</body>` tag. It's recommended to put before the `</body>` tag, because it won't block the rendering of the page.

Then, to do the collpasing functionality, first of all add a class to the elements you want to be collapsed, and hide them with css. Then, attach a click event to them, which would toggle their visibility, like so:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(".element").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

All your jQuery code should go after you've loaded the jQuery library in your `HTML`. You can see that I've wrapped the code in `$(document).ready();`. We do this to make sure that our code will start to run only after the DOM has been loaded.

I hope this gives you a quick overview on solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very good. I understand much better now. 5 stars sir.....i apriciate it explained at novice.

Comment: @user5474108 If this helped you, you can mark it as correct answer by clicking the √ icon in the left of this answer, and also voting it up. Glad it helped you.